# Hide/Show DIV based on option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS beginner here so any help is appreciated.

I am trying to get show/hide DIV based on JS.

I am using the following:

HTML

```
<Select id="single-option-selector-product-template-0">
   <option value="White">White</option>
   <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
   <option value="Heather Ash">Heather Ash</option>
   <option value="Heather Grey">Heather Grey</option>
</Select>
<div id="White" class="colours" style="display:none"> White </div>
<div id="Navy" class="colours" style="display:none"> Navy </div>
<div id="Heather Ash" class="colours" style="display:none">Heather Ash </div>
<div id="Heather Grey" class="colours" style="display:none"> Heather Grey </div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#single-option-selector-product-template-0').change(function(){
            $('.colours').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

Single words option like White and Navy are working fine but not those with 2 or more words like Heather Ash and Heather Grey.  The option values are created when I create product in Shopify.

Comment: value cannot have spaces, so try like this Heather_ash

Comment: @Khalid, no thats not true, spaces can be there in the value

Comment: Okay, Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can you should avoid `id` values with spaces in them as they can be hard to work with. However, if you have *no control* over the `id` values in your HTML, you can use [`$.escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) (available since jQuery 3.0) to work around the fact that you have a space in your `id` value which would otherwise cause (for example) `#Heather Ash` to look for an `Ash` element under `#Heather`.

```js
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#single-option-selector-product-template-0').change(function(){
            $('.colours').hide();
            $('#' + $.escapeSelector($(this).val())).show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="single-option-selector-product-template-0">
   <option value="White">White</option>
   <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
   <option value="Heather Ash">Heather Ash</option>
   <option value="Heather Grey">Heather Grey</option>
</Select>
<div id="White" class="colours" style="display:none"> White </div>
<div id="Navy" class="colours" style="display:none"> Navy </div>
<div id="Heather Ash" class="colours" style="display:none">Heather Ash </div>
<div id="Heather Grey" class="colours" style="display:none"> Heather Grey </div>
```

Comment: FYI, It is still the bad practice to use separated words as an element ID

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal absolutely but some times you have no control over the selectors you are given - OP gets theirs from Shopify so may not have control.

Comment: @ClementCkh you haven't made the modifications I made in my answer. It is working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/uasbrenj/

Comment: Thanks.  I accidentally used jQuery 1.9.1 before and didn't worked.  Changed to jQuery 3.3.1 and all good now!

Comment: Hmm .. after copying the same code into my Shopify template file it didn't work again.  I checked and I have jQuery 3.3.1 loaded for sure.   Even White and Navy is not showing the hidden DIV.

Comment: @ClementCkh if you've definitely got jQuery 3.x loaded it should work fine. Perhaps an older version is also being loaded? Without being able to see your template page output it's hard to guess what might be going wrong. If you can make a fiddle that replicates the problem I can take a look....

Comment: I added something to my JSFiddle, basically trying to get option value string and remove white space so that #Heather Ash becomes #HeatherAsh, then compare.  I am not sure if it's possible .. I updated it but doesn't seem to work ==> https://jsfiddle.net/clemckh/qtwuhb7r/11/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `id` values that has whitespace separated words. You can join them using underscore and use the same value as a `value` of your `<option>` element:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#single-option-selector-product-template-0').change(function() {
    $('.colours').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="single-option-selector-product-template-0">
  <option value="White">White</option>
  <option value="Navy">Navy</option>
  <option value="Heather_Ash">Heather Ash</option>
  <option value="Heather_Grey">Heather Grey</option>
</Select>
<div id="White" class="colours" style="display:none"> White </div>
<div id="Navy" class="colours" style="display:none"> Navy </div>
<div id="Heather_Ash" class="colours" style="display:none">Heather Ash </div>
<div id="Heather_Grey" class="colours" style="display:none"> Heather Grey </div>
```

> id's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.). Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID value.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option>Choose Color</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```